How to make mirror with loop0 from striped loop1 and loop2?
I have one 500M disk and two 250M disks.
How to accomplish two disk into RAID0 and then mirror it onto 500M?
I have the next configuration:
btrfs fi usage -T /mnt/raid_test/
Overall:
    Device size:        1000.00MiB
    Device allocated:        535.00MiB
    Device unallocated:      465.00MiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:            407.17MiB
    Free (estimated):        472.16MiB  (min: 277.47MiB)
    Free (statfs, df):        20.95MiB
    Data ratio:               1.09
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:        5.50MiB  (used: 0.00B)
    Multiple profiles:             yes  (data)

              Data      Data     Data    Metadata  System              
Id Path       single    RAID1    RAID10  RAID1     RAID1    Unallocated
-- ---------- --------- -------- ------- --------- -------- -----------
 1 /dev/loop1 189.00MiB 12.00MiB       -  32.00MiB  8.00MiB     9.00MiB
 2 /dev/loop2 192.00MiB 17.00MiB       -  32.00MiB  8.00MiB     1.00MiB
 3 /dev/loop0         - 29.00MiB       -         -        -   471.00MiB
-- ---------- --------- -------- ------- --------- -------- -----------
   Total      381.00MiB 29.00MiB 8.00MiB  32.00MiB  8.00MiB   481.00MiB
   Used       373.95MiB 16.05MiB   0.00B 560.00KiB 16.00KiB            


When I tried to start re balance it I got error:
 btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid10 -mconvert=raid10 /mnt/raid_test/
ERROR: error during balancing '/mnt/raid_test/': Read-only file system
There may be more info in syslog - try dmesg | tail
root@work:/mnt# dmesg | tail
[33384.890087] BTRFS info (device loop1: state A): chunk_block_rsv: size 655360 reserved 655360
[33384.890088] BTRFS info (device loop1: state A): delayed_block_rsv: size 0 reserved 0
[33384.890090] BTRFS info (device loop1: state A): delayed_refs_rsv: size 262144 reserved 0
[33384.890092] BTRFS: error (device loop1: state A) in do_chunk_alloc:3895: errno=-28 No space left
[33384.890096] BTRFS info (device loop1: state EA): forced readonly
[33384.890107] BTRFS: error (device loop1: state EA) in btrfs_create_pending_block_groups:2711: errno=-28 No space left
[33384.890113] BTRFS: error (device loop1: state EA) in btrfs_create_pending_block_groups:2718: errno=-28 No space left
[33384.890118] BTRFS: error (device loop1: state EA) in btrfs_create_pending_block_groups:2723: errno=-28 No space left
[33384.890123] BTRFS: error (device loop1: state EA) in add_block_group_free_space:1396: errno=-28 No space left
[33384.890139] BTRFS info (device loop1: state EA): balance: ended with status: -30

When I created 500M+250M+250M from scratch I can see that I can store only 375Mb on this configuration. 250M on the disk with 500M are unused.
Is there a way to explicitly stripe 250+250 and mirror them to 500?
Another try. Create 500M device then try to add two 250M devices and activate mirror on them:
root@work:/mnt# mkfs.btrfs -f /dev/loop0 
btrfs-progs v5.16.2
See http://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org for more information.

Performing full device TRIM /dev/loop0 (500.00MiB) ...
NOTE: several default settings have changed in version 5.15, please make sure
      this does not affect your deployments:
      - DUP for metadata (-m dup)
      - enabled no-holes (-O no-holes)
      - enabled free-space-tree (-R free-space-tree)

Label:              (null)
UUID:               7077425f-8f99-416c-91ff-265740c827e9
Node size:          16384
Sector size:        4096
Filesystem size:    500.00MiB
Block group profiles:
  Data:             single            8.00MiB
  Metadata:         DUP              32.00MiB
  System:           DUP               8.00MiB
SSD detected:       yes
Zoned device:       no
Incompat features:  extref, skinny-metadata, no-holes
Runtime features:   free-space-tree
Checksum:           crc32c
Number of devices:  1
Devices:
   ID        SIZE  PATH
    1   500.00MiB  /dev/loop0

root@work:/mnt# mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/raid_test/
root@work:/mnt# btrfs fi usage -T /mnt/raid_test/
Overall:
    Device size:         500.00MiB
    Device allocated:         88.00MiB
    Device unallocated:      412.00MiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:            288.00KiB
    Free (estimated):        420.00MiB  (min: 214.00MiB)
    Free (statfs, df):       419.00MiB
    Data ratio:               1.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:        5.50MiB  (used: 0.00B)
    Multiple profiles:              no

              Data    Metadata  System              
Id Path       single  DUP       DUP      Unallocated
-- ---------- ------- --------- -------- -----------
 1 /dev/loop0 8.00MiB  64.00MiB 16.00MiB   412.00MiB
-- ---------- ------- --------- -------- -----------
   Total      8.00MiB  32.00MiB  8.00MiB   412.00MiB
   Used         0.00B 128.00KiB 16.00KiB            
root@work:/mnt# dd if=/dev/random of=raid_test/garbage.img bs=1M count=400
400+0 records in
400+0 records out
419430400 bytes (419 MB, 400 MiB) copied, 0,791838 s, 530 MB/s
root@work:/mnt# ls -lah /mnt/raid_test/
total 401M
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   22 Oct  6 21:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   34 Oct  6 21:53 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 400M Oct  6 21:59 garbage.img
root@work:/mnt# btrfs fi usage -T /mnt/raid_test/
Overall:
    Device size:         500.00MiB
    Device allocated:        484.00MiB
    Device unallocated:       16.00MiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:            288.00KiB
    Free (estimated):        420.00MiB  (min: 412.00MiB)
    Free (statfs, df):       419.00MiB
    Data ratio:               1.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:        5.50MiB  (used: 16.00KiB)
    Multiple profiles:              no

              Data      Metadata  System              
Id Path       single    DUP       DUP      Unallocated
-- ---------- --------- --------- -------- -----------
 1 /dev/loop0 404.00MiB  64.00MiB 16.00MiB    16.00MiB
-- ---------- --------- --------- -------- -----------
   Total      404.00MiB  32.00MiB  8.00MiB    16.00MiB
   Used           0.00B 128.00KiB 16.00KiB            
root@work:/mnt# btrfs device add -f /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 /mnt/raid_test/
Performing full device TRIM /dev/loop1 (250.00MiB) ...
Performing full device TRIM /dev/loop2 (250.00MiB) ...
root@work:/mnt# btrfs fi usage -T /mnt/raid_test/
Overall:
    Device size:        1000.00MiB
    Device allocated:        484.00MiB
    Device unallocated:      516.00MiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:            401.09MiB
    Free (estimated):        520.00MiB  (min: 262.00MiB)
    Free (statfs, df):       517.00MiB
    Data ratio:               1.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:        5.50MiB  (used: 0.00B)
    Multiple profiles:              no

              Data      Metadata  System              
Id Path       single    DUP       DUP      Unallocated
-- ---------- --------- --------- -------- -----------
 1 /dev/loop0 404.00MiB  64.00MiB 16.00MiB    16.00MiB
 2 /dev/loop1         -         -        -   250.00MiB
 3 /dev/loop2         -         -        -   250.00MiB
-- ---------- --------- --------- -------- -----------
   Total      404.00MiB  32.00MiB  8.00MiB   516.00MiB
   Used       400.00MiB 544.00KiB 16.00KiB            
root@work:/mnt# btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid10 -mconvert=raid10 /mnt/raid_test/
ERROR: error during balancing '/mnt/raid_test/': No space left on device
There may be more info in syslog - try dmesg | tail
# dmesg | tail
[35650.111656] BTRFS info (device loop0): relocating block group 131072000 flags data
[35650.115638] BTRFS info (device loop0): relocating block group 63963136 flags data
[35650.120370] BTRFS info (device loop0): relocating block group 30408704 flags metadata|dup
[35650.128752] BTRFS info (device loop0): found 25 extents, stage: move data extents
[35650.135021] BTRFS info (device loop0): relocating block group 22020096 flags system|dup
[35650.141421] BTRFS info (device loop0): relocating block group 13631488 flags data
[35650.167757] BTRFS info (device loop0): found 1 extents, stage: move data extents
[35650.186443] BTRFS info (device loop0): found 1 extents, stage: update data pointers
[35650.193078] BTRFS info (device loop0): 6 enospc errors during balance
[35650.193084] BTRFS info (device loop0): balance: ended with status: -28

Here is not clear to me, why on 500M device space is disappears during adding two 250M devices.
